# Using characters as indices in arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int arr[128];
    arr['a'] = 101;
    cout<<arr['a'];

    return 0;
}
```

So i was experimenting around and found that characters can be used as indices in arrays instead of conventional whole numbers.
This program gives the correct output i.e 101 which is correct.

But how does this all work? Like in terms of space allocation and reference to that element.

**Questions:**

1. 128 blocks of int were declared which is a total of 512 bytes. How does the program store '101' in a char block i.e in a placeholder 'a' which is char? What does space allocation look like?
2. Why doesn't this program work when I reduce the number of indices of array below 128?
3. How does program refer to '101' through 'a' since this isn't a map but an array?

Comment: This should be covered in any introductory text. Every `char`  has a corresponding ASCII value that is an `int`.

Comment: And on the rare system where the character encoding is not ASCII, the principle will be exactly the same.

Comment: Interesting fun fact: `int` is not always 32 bits. The only guarantees you get in c++ about the size of `int` is its at least 16 bits and no larger than the size of `long`. Similar is true of `char`. I have seen systems where `char`, `short`, `int`, and (I think) `long` were all 32 bits. So technically the 128 `int` array could be anywhere between 256 bytes and infinity. Fun huh? Because the integers can vary in size C introduced (and C++  later adopted) [fixed width Integers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`'a'` is a `char` type with an implementation defined numeric value (depends on the character *encoding* used on your platform: in ASCII, it's 97).

That numeric `char` is used in the evaluation of `arr['a']`. If you're fortunate, that will give you an element of the `arr`. If the value is outside the *bounds* of `arr` then the behaviour of the program is undefined.

Answer (score 4):

`char`s are just smaller `int`s with a fancy way of printing them. A `char` in fact holds the ASCII value of the character it represents. `a` has the ASCII value of 97, so your snippet is in fact equivalent to:

```
int arr[128];
arr[97] = 101;
cout<<arr[97];
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be ASCII though.

Comment: my bad. it was such a simple concept. should have got it. Thanks anyways x

Comment: "chars are just smaller ints" -> not necessarily. They are just not allowed to be larger than ints.